# Split a collection into n parts with Lambda (or LINQ), in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

Example of code presented below is working fine, it's doing what is supposed to do, but I'm not satisfied. Looking for much smarter solution in VB.NET. The presentation of results (I mean counts for each subgroup) is quite awkward. The content of data and list of records etc. are not important. Also counts should be sorted in order Less{0}, From{1}To{2}, MoreThan{3}...Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim Age1 As Integer = 5
    Dim Age2 As Integer = 9
    Dim myList As New List(Of Integer) = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 9, 11}
    Dim Lambda = myList.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Age1 = (x) < Age1,Key .Age2 = (x) > Age1 - 1 And (x) <= Age2,Key .Age3 = (x) > Age2}).ToList()
    Dim group1, group2, group3 As Integer
    myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToList()
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", myList.Select(Function(s) s.ToString).ToArray))
    For Each group In Lambda
        If group.Key.Age1 Then group1 = group.Count()
        If group.Key.Age2 Then group2 = group.Count()
        If group.Key.Age3 Then group3 = group.Count()
    Next
    ' Obviously If Stop Then Error condition
    If group1 + group2 + group3 <> myList.Count Then Stop

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Groups: Less{0},From{1}To{2},MoreThan{3}", Age1, Age1, Age2 - 1, Age2))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   Age:  {0,4},{1,8},{2,8}", group1, group2, group3))
    '1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11
    'Groups: Less5,From5To8,MoreThan9
    'Age:     6,      12,        2
```

Comment: Counting, sorting, grouping... all sounds like `DataTable` operations. Maybe that would make the code smell nice to you?

Comment: @Jacob H ...In my case using 'DataTable' is out of question. I'm dealing with very large data sets and only 'List' is an alternative. Group By is actually doing an excelent job... Also sorting is not necessary. Much  faster is to sort few numbers afterwards than millions before...There must be somewhere a trick with nicer syntax...

Comment: In C# it would be a lot less verbose ;) but I will see if I can translate to VB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would try to improve it:

```
Dim Age1 As Integer = 5
Dim Age2 As Integer = 9

Dim myList As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 9, 11}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x)))
console.WriteLine

Dim ageBins = myList.GroupBy(Function(age) If(age < Age1, 1, If(age >= Age1 And age <= Age2, 2, 3))) _
                    .Select(Function(agebin) New With { agebin.Key, .AgeCount = agebin.Count() }) _
                    .OrderBy(Function(agebin) agebin.Key)

For Each bin In ageBins
    Dim msg As String
    Select bin.Key
        Case 1
            msg = $"Less {Age1}"
        Case 2
            msg = $"From {Age1} To {Age2}"
        Case Else
            msg = $"MoreThan {Age2}"
    End Select
    Console.WriteLine($"{msg,12}: {bin.AgeCount}")
Next
```

You could also change the code to handle any number of bins:

```
Dim agesForBins = {5, 10}
Dim ageBins = myList.GroupBy(Function(age) Enumerable.Range(0, agesForBins.Length).Where(Function(n) age < agesForBins(n)).DefaultIfEmpty(agesForBins.Length).First) _
                    .Select(Function(agebin) New With { agebin.Key, .AgeCount = agebin.Count() }) _
                    .OrderBy(Function(agebin) agebin.Key)

For Each bin In ageBins
    Dim msg As String
    If bin.Key = 0 Then
        msg = $"Less {agesForBins(0)}"
    ElseIf bin.Key = agesForBins.Length Then
        msg = $"MoreThan {agesForBins(bin.Key-1)-1}"
    Else
        msg = $"From {agesForBins(bin.Key-1)} To {agesForBins(bin.Key)-1}"
    End If

    Console.WriteLine($"{msg,12}: {bin.AgeCount}")
Next
```

Comment: Very nice...   Can't cast the vote because don't have sufficient reputations! Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this is the simplest way to do it:

```
Dim Age1 As Integer = 5
Dim Age2 As Integer = 9
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 9, 11}

Dim group1 As Integer = myList.Where(Function (x) x < Age1).Count()
Dim group2 As Integer = myList.Where(Function (x) x > Age1 - 1 And x <= Age2).Count()
Dim group3 As Integer = myList.Where(Function (x) x > Age2).Count()

If group1 + group2 + group3 <> myList.Count Then Stop

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Groups: Less{0},From{1}To{2},MoreThan{3}", Age1, Age1, Age2 - 1, Age2))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   Age:  {0,4},{1,8},{2,8}", group1, group2, group3))
```

---

If you want a funky LINQ-based method then try this:

```
Dim bands() As Func(Of Integer, Boolean) = _
{ _
    Function (x) x < Age1, _
    Function (x) x <= Age2, _
    Function (x) True _
}

Dim counts = _
    myList _
        .GroupBy(Function (x) Enumerable.Range(0, bands.Count).Where(Function (n) bands(n)(x)).First()) _
        .Select(Function (x) x.Count()) _
        .ToArray()

Dim group1 As Integer = counts(0)
Dim group2 As Integer = counts(1)
Dim group3 As Integer = counts(2)
```

Comment: Very fast, fastest algorithm so far (using myList.Where)... But can't cast the vote because don't have sufficient reputations (only 11!) Thanks very much as your post has given me idea of recursive solution for n bands required...

Comment: @ATeDe - Why recursive? n-bands would work fine using my `bands` approach.

Comment: @ATeDe you can still "accept" the answer without upvoting it.

Comment: @Jacob H -Yeah, I did but don't know what is the outcome of it, as I'm very unprivileged member...

Comment: @ATeDe if you accepted the post it would show a check mark. So you haven't yet. It will give you some karma points if you do, and that will let you upvote later.

Comment: The problem with your first method is you go through `myList` once for every bin, which isn't very efficient if `myList` is large or expensive to enumerate.

Comment: @NetMage My 1st method is gone. Thinking of recursively doing bin by bin on a shrinking myList. It might be fastest algorithm... Thanks for support

Comment: @ATeDe - It's unlikely to be faster if you're building new lists each time. It'll be creating a lot of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2'nd fastest and I think quite 'clean' solution based on @Enigmativity concept posted a couple of hours ago...Takes a care of his n-bands approach

```
Function simpleCSVsplit(ageForBins() As Integer, myList As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim Bands As New List(Of Integer)
    For indx As Integer = 0 To ageForBins.Count - 1
        Bands.Add(myList.Where(Function(x) x < ageForBins(indx)).Count())
        myList = myList.Skip(Bands(indx)).ToList()
    Next
    Bands.Add(myList.Count)
    Return Bands
End Function
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that above example requires sorting before SimpleSplit function is called...                                                                                myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToList()                                  
Dim resu As List(Of Integer) = simpleCSVsplitB(agesForBins, myList) 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Final Cut: {0}", String.Join(",", resu)))

Comment: Note that this also assumes you have sorted `agesForBins` ascending.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's coming nicely. Already tested on real live "Age" data extracted  from over  150K records containing more than 40 columns of data. Once is fully tested we may convert to C#.  It would be a smash.